# Modify JSON fomat to work with JavaScript template library

Tags: javascript, json, templates, mustache

I am trying to take a userlist stored as JSON and use it to parse a template using JavaScript.

With the library Mustache, it would be done like this...

```
var output = $("#output"); 

// template stored in JS var as a string
var templateString = '<div>'+
'<ul>'+
'  <li>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} goes by the username of: {{user_name}}</li>'+
'</ul>'+
'</div>';

// parse template stored in JS string var
var html = Mustache.render(templateString, jsonData);
output.append(html);
```

In this example above it would parse the JSON data from `var jsonData` using the template strored in `var templateString`

The issue I have is that my JSON data is not in the correct format that Mustache templates require.

instead of this format...

```
var jsonData = { 
    "1":{  
        "id":"1",
        "user_name":"jasondavis",
        "first_name":"Jason",
        "last_name":"Davis",
        "is_admin":"1",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad":{  
        "id":"1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad",
        "user_name":"Jeff",
        "first_name":"Jeff",
        "last_name":"Mosley",
        "is_admin":"1",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    }
};
```

---

**Mustache expects this JSON format...**

```
var jsonData2 = { 
"users":[
{  
    "id":"1",
    "user_name":"jasondavis",
    "first_name":"Jason",
    "last_name":"Davis",
    "is_admin":"1",
    "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
    "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
},
{  
    "id":"1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad",
    "user_name":"Jeff",
    "first_name":"Jeff",
    "last_name":"Mosley",
    "is_admin":"1",
    "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
    "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
}
]};
```

**and this template...notice addition of `{{#users}}` and `{{/users}}` wrapped around `<li>` tags**

```
// template stored in JS var as a string
var templateString = '<div>'+
'<ul>'+
'{{#users}}'+
'  <li>{{first_name}} {{last_name}} goes by the username of: {{user_name}}</li>'+
'{{/users}}'+
'</ul>'+
'</div>';
```

---

As my JSON data already comes in this format below... is there a way to make it work with the templates or must the JSON be altered once I get it?

Any help appreciated.

JSFIddle demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/utgrLw96/25/

```
var jsonData = { 
    "1":{  
        "id":"1",
        "user_name":"jasondavis",
        "first_name":"Jason",
        "last_name":"Davis",
        "is_admin":"1",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    },
    "1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad":{  
        "id":"1702c3d0-df12-2d1b-d964-521becb5e3ad",
        "user_name":"Jeff",
        "first_name":"Jeff",
        "last_name":"Mosley",
        "is_admin":"1",
        "gravatar_id":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "gravatar_url":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/5359bf585d11c5c35602f9bf5e66fa5e?s=80&d=identicon&r=PG"
    }
};
```

Comment: `parse the JSON data from var jsonData` - despite what you are calling the variable, var jsonData needs no parsing as it is not JSON data

Comment: @JaromandaX so perhaps on my PHP JSON generation side I need to consider changing the format this data is generated in?  When I run this through a JSON validator it shows it is correct though?

Comment: no, just saying you don't need to JSON.parse data that isn't JSON

Comment: @JaromandaX I see, all I meant by parsing was to process the JSON data into the template.  Not sure how I can use this existing JSON though

Answer (score 0):

As it was already pointed out in a comment, your `jsonData` is not JSON, but a javascript object. You can modify it easily with jQuery (as you are already using it).

```
var usersArray = $.map(jsonData, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
var mustacheData = {users: usersArray};
```

This isn't enough for you, though. Your template is meant to be for a list of users, but now it tells Mustache it is just one user.
Your template should look like this:

```
var templateString = "
  <div><ul>
    {{#users}}
    <li>{{first_name}}{{last_name}} goes by the username of:{{user_name}}</li>
    {{/users}}
  <div><ul>
";
```

(I know you already brought it up, but now it works with the new data, so I added this in the answer.)

Corrected [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4v1yvw6/)

Answer (score 0):

I looped through  your `jsonData` using `jQuery.each` function, and I think it is enough to create your expected result:

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key,val) {

     var html = Mustache.to_html(templateString, val);

     output.append(html);
});
```

Please to look at the updated [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/utgrLw96/27/)

Comment: What is your feedback concerning this. Thanks